# How do I put string at the end of every line?

Tags: python, string

I am wondering how could I add " Hello " to the end of every line?

Example:

```
Super 
Cool
Fun
```

Output:

```
Super Hello
Cool Hello
Fun Hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lines = "Foo\nBar\nBaz"

for line in lines.splitlines():
    print "%s Hello" % line
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the string function replace.  It would look like:

```
In [3]: a = 'Super\n Cool\n Fun\n' 

In [4]: a.replace('\n', ' Hello \n')
Out[4]: 'Super Hello \n Cool Hello \n Fun Hello \n'
```

Comment: Im, not sure why but it didnt work. Thank you for replying though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Bob - this does work for me, can you show us your code in the question?

Comment: I copied and pasted that directly from my IPython window, so I am not sure why it would not work for you.  Please forgive me for asking an obvious question, but you are trimming off the line numbers and In/Out identifiers from IPython before you try executing, right?

Answer (score 0):

`['%s hello' % s for s in ['super', 'cool', 'fun']]`

If your data is in a list.

Comment: My data is in a string, err, is this possible with strings?

Comment: Is each string delimited with \n?

Comment: No they are not, the it is a multiline string like in the example

Comment: @Bob, what do you mean by a multiline string? A string has multiple "lines" when there are one or more newline characters ('\n').